# Android on click set imageview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick, imageview

so I have an android project that makes use of recyclerview and cardview, where I set a background imageview on click of a card. This is my code:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.Viewholder> {
private ArrayList <Integer> mImages = new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerViewAdapter( Context mContext, ArrayList<Integer> mImages) {
    this.mImages = mImages;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemlist,viewGroup,false);

    return new Viewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Viewholder viewholder, int i) {
    viewholder.img.setImageResource(mImages.get(i));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mImages.size();
}

public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    ImageView img;
    ImageView imv;

    public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        imv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Clicked");
        int position = getLayoutPosition();
        imv.setImageResource(R.drawable.vehicles);

    }
}
}
```

But it doesn't work on click and the app just crashes. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Include error log in question content please.

Comment: Can you post this 'R.layout.itemlist' layout

Comment: There error is:

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

You must define your itemView as clickable for receiving click events.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: this won't help

Answer (score 0):

please try move onClickListener to onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Viewholder viewholder, int i) {
    viewholder.img.setImageResource(mImages.get(i));
    viewholder.img.setOnClickListener(v -> {
      // your code
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view){
         //your code
     }
 });
```

Comment: no, `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)` is just fine - there is no need in creating an anonymous `OnClickListener` class

Comment: `itemView` - that `View` was clcked